# How can I get invites for a member in Twilio Chat using Twilio Chat Swift SDK

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I was able to invite a member to a private channel. I would like to display all the invites for a particular member and give them the option of accepting / declining an invitation. I've been through the documentation but I couldn't find how to list all the invitations for a member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Turns out the only way to access invites is using channels. Fetching all subscribed channels for a member and comparing channel status with invited gave me required result.